# Why Javascript string.replace("\n\t","xxx") replaces "\n\t" with "\nxxx"?

Tags: javascript, regex, control-characters

I expect to replace `"\n\t"` with `"xxx"` in a `txt` file:

```
"数字多功能光盘    DVD shùzì"
```

I do this: `str.replace("\n\t","xxx")`
method matches needed parts but leaves `\n` part and only replaces `\t` for `'xxx'`.WHY?

why when use `crtl+F` in `VSCOde` and it works like charm but in code it doesn't.

Comment: A newline may be `\r`, `\n`, or `\r\n`. To replace all of these options, use `str.replace(/(?:\r\n?|\n)\t/, "xxx");`

Comment: WTF!? I've spend 2 hours debugging! :( How do you know this? Thanks

Comment: Research and memory? http://www.regular-expressions.info/, http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html, https://regex101.com/, https://regexr.com/

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `str.replace("a","b")` only replaces the first occurrence in JavaScript. To replace all of them, you need to use a regex with `g` modifier. So, you could try `str.replace(/\n\t/g,"xxx")` first.

Next, why does it work in VSCode? In VSCode regex, `\n` matches any line break sequence that is selected in the bottom right-hand corner of VSCode app. It works as `\R` in PCRE, Java, Onigmo, etc. in this case.

As there can be many line ending sequences you may consider "converting" VSCode `\n` to `(?:\r\n|[\r\n\x0B\x0C\x85\u2028\u2029])` that matches any single Unicode line break sequence and use

```
s = s.replace(/(?:\r\n|[\r\n\x0B\x0C\x85\u2028\u2029])\t/g, '')
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that. Why does VScode do so? What is it's logic?

Comment: @coobit Probably, the main point was to make the regex more line-oriented, as in Vim. Matching linebreaks in VSCode wth regex has always been a pain. E.g. by default, `[\s\S]` does not match line breaks, it only works when you add `\r` or `\n` there. I think developers tried to make their regex implementation "smarter". In fact, it only confuses users. If your file line endings are CRLF, I'd expect to match them with `\r\n`, but it is not the case :(.